# Overlaps between Paradise Kiss & Nana?

Tags: nana, paradise-kiss

At the end of some of the chapters of *Nana*, some characters from Ai Yazawa's other manga *Paradise Kiss* show up at 'Junko's Place' (the bonus section) and chat with some of the *Nana* cast.

Is there a similar section in *Paradise Kiss*? Are there any further overlaps between the two series?

Comment: In episode 6 of paradise kiss at 14:50 I think nana made an appearance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Paradise Kiss* is actually set in the same universe as *Gokinjo Monogatari*, another work by Ai Yazawa. There are bonus sections in *Paradise Kiss*, but from what I can tell (at least from the first bonus section on chapter 10), it shares characters from *Gokinjo Monogatari* instead. According to [Wikia](http://parakiss.wikia.com/wiki/Paradise_Kiss), *Paradise Kiss* is actually the sequel to *Gokinjo Monogatari*.

*Paradise Kiss* and *Nana* were published by different companies, so it is likely that they are not allowed to have much cross-over between the two. As far as I can tell, there is no other cross-over between *Paradise Kiss* and *Nana*. The only example I can find of a possible cross-over (other than in the bonus sections), is from a [random forum](http://www.gaiaonline.com/forum/manga/a-small-connection-between-nana-and-paradise-kiss/t.46784187/) where a person mentions that a dress donated in *Paradise Kiss* is bought in *Nana*, but that hasn't been substantiated.